# Null Value when using IQueryable with Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Lets say I have this `IQueryable` variable :

```
var result= (from fruit in fruitTable 
                 join dapple in applesIQuery on fruit.fruitType equals dapple.fruitType into apples 
                 from apple in apples.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new foo );
```

applesIQuery comes from another `IQueryable` that consists of another group of joins.

```
applesIQuery =(from a in anotherTable select new {id = foo}) ;
```

I need to treat the case where `applesIQuery == null`, basically creating a List of 1 element with id=0 , but without transforming the `IQueryable` into an `IEnumerable`. Something like :

```
applesIQuery =(from a in anotherTable select new {id = foo})?? Iqueriable {new {id=0}} ;
```

Any pointers towards the right direction ?

Comment: You can certainly construct such a query but it will fail at runtime because EF cannot translate it. EF LINQ support is very poor and bolted on.

Comment: one solution would be building a poco entioty for that query.I'd need to do so for future queries;and thats something that I would like to avoid

Comment: My point is that EF cannot process any kind of query where you create a sequence yourself. Does not matter what's in it (be it an entity, some other object or a simple integer). It will compile and error out.

Comment: how can applesIQuery be null as the result of `(from a in anotherTable select new {id = foo})` ? Theorically you should call .Count() on the result of the query. So imho, with the disclosed piece of code, applesIQuery is never null.

Comment: The code posted is there just to create a scenario . Basically apples is a join between 9 tables ( 3 inner joins , 6 left outer joins ) , and the result is null in some cases.

Comment: well try a select().Take(0)... may be it will do. (not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applesIQuery is of type IQueryable and will not be null.  Assuming you mean that if the query does not return any results, try something like this:

```
applesIQuery = applesIQuery.Count() == 0 ? new ArrayList(){ new { id = 0 } }.AsQueryable() : applesIQuery;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I used .Took me a while to reach the conclusion :)